# Good authentication gems for Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, authentication, sinatra

Are there any good authentication gems out there for Sinatra? I'm fully aware there are great solutions for rails but I would be happy with something as simple as [clearance](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance) but for the life of me I can't find anything decent or up to date.

I'm also aware omniauth is around and can be used as a solution. Short of any gems doesn't anyone know of any good up to date tutorials.

What I'm looking for is a gem almost identical to clearance but that will work with Sinatra apps.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends how you're trying to auth users.

If they're logging in with Facebook or any other OAuth service, Omniauth is the best way to handle that.

If you're looking to do more simple email/password auth, Sinatra has some nice [built in](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#auth) solutions (which it inherits from Rack, the tech upon which it's built).

Which of these (or something else entirely) is most applicable to you?

Comment: Omniauth is a great solution for oauth thing but I would like to do email and password and with something that looks nicer than basic http authentication

Comment: "looks nicer" What do you mean by that? More featureful? It really depends how you're storing auth info. [Parse](https://parse.com) does a lot of nice auth stuff if you want to use that as your backend (or even just for auth).

Comment: Sorry I mean a system that can be integrated into the ui. Basic http auth just comes as a popup box built into the browser.

Comment: I'm not really following. Can you edit your OP to explain more explicitly what you're asking? Near as I can tell you want oauth because it's more involved than email/password auth?